# React Native application freezes while fetching API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, freeze

Hi I have very common problem, react native application freezes while fetching API,
It is like when you fetching you cannot click or do anythink till your fetching ends.

This is my code where I call function which fetchs APi

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList } from "react-native";

// Api`s
import { topCategory } from "../../api/appModels/category";
import { banners } from "../../api/appModels/slider";
import { dinamicBlocks } from "../../api/appModels/product";

// Hooks
import useApi from "../../Hooks/useApi";

// UI-Components
import Container from "../../uicomponents/General/Container";
import BannerSlider from "../../uicomponents/Slider/BannerSlider";
import Screen from "../../uicomponents/General/Screen";
import TopProductPattern from "../../uicomponents/Category/pattern/TopProductPattern";
import SliderPlaceholder from "../../uicomponents/Skeleton/Sliders/SliderPlaceholder";
import CategoryAvatarPlaceholder from "../../uicomponents/Skeleton/Category/CategoryAvatarPlaceholder";
import CategoryBlocks from "../../uicomponents/Product/blocks/CategoryBlocks";
import Header from "../../uicomponents/header/Header";
import ActivityIndicator from "../../uicomponents/Loaders/ActivityIndicator";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const {
    data: topCategoryList,
    loading: topCategoryLoading,
    request: categoryRequest,
  } = useApi(topCategory);

  const {
    data: bannersList,
    loading: bannerLoading,
    request: bannersRequest,
  } = useApi(banners);

  const {
    loading: blocksLoading,
    request: blocksRequest,
  } = useApi(dinamicBlocks);

  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([]);
  const [indexing, setIndexing] = useState(1);
  const [countBlocks, setCountBlocks] = useState(0);
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Calling Api`s
    categoryRequest();
    bannersRequest();
    blocksRequest((item) => {
      setIndexing(indexing + 1);
      setBlocks(item["blocks"]);
      setCountBlocks(item["count"]);
    }, 1);
  }, []);

  const loadMore = () => {
    if (!blocksLoading) {
      blocksRequest((item) => {
        setIndexing(indexing + 1);
        setBlocks(blocks.concat(item["blocks"]));
        console.log(item);
      }, indexing);
      setLoader(indexing != countBlocks);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <FlatList
        data={blocks}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.categories.toString()}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <>
            <Header />
            {bannerLoading ? (
              <SliderPlaceholder />
            ) : (
              <BannerSlider data={bannersList} dots />
            )}
            <Container>
              <View style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
                {topCategoryLoading ? (
                  <CategoryAvatarPlaceholder />
                ) : (
                  <TopProductPattern data={topCategoryList} />
                )}
              </View>
            </Container>
          </>
        }
        ListFooterComponent={<ActivityIndicator visible={loader} />}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CategoryBlocks title={item.blocks_name} data={item.categoriesList} />
        )}
        onEndReached={loadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Here is my code which fetches API

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useApi = (apiFunc) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const request = async (callBack = () => {}, ...args) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await apiFunc(...args);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(response.problem);

    setLoading(false);

    setError("");
    setData(response.data);
    if (response.ok) {
      callBack(response.data);
    }
  };

  return {
    data,
    error,
    loading,
    request,
    setLoading,
    setData,
  };
};

export default useApi;
```

I think there is problem with RN-bridge HELP ME PLEASE !

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's happened because you set **onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}** and when data was loaded one more time request will be send and it's make problem.

So you can increase this value for example to *0.7*.

In the official react native website This is how it is explained  onEndReachedThreshold:

"How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the bottom edge of the list must be from the end of the content to trigger the onEndReached callback. Thus a value of 0.5 will trigger onEndReached when the end of the content is within half the visible length of the list."

Comment: Thank you for answering but no way, it didn`t help.